# How to translate from a PostgreSQL jsonpath to the text[] parameter for usage in jsonb_set() or jsonb_insert()

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonpath

I'd like to use the PostgreSQL specific functions `jsonb_set()` or `jsonb_insert()`, which look a lot like their [MySQL equivalents](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set), and share some functionality with [Oracle's `JSON_TRANSFORM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_TRANSFORM.html#GUID-DD2A821B-C688-4310-81B5-5F45090B9366). But I'd like to work with a `jsonpath` specification, e.g.

```sql
-- Hypothetical syntax
SELECT jsonb_set('{"a": 1}'::jsonb, jsonpath_to_text_array('$.b'), '[1, 2]');

-- Equivalent to:
SELECT jsonb_set('{"a": 1}'::jsonb, '{b}', '[1, 2]');
```

To produce:

```
{"a": 1, "b": [2, 3]}
```

Assuming I cannot manually re-write the JSON path to the `text[]` representation, because I'm making query agnostic tooling, and as such, do not know the JSON path expressions in advance (they can even be dynamic expressions), is there a `jsonpath_to_text_array()` function that does this transformation for me, at least whenever it's "reasonably" possibe?

Comment: I don't think such a function exists, and if it did, it could only convert very basic JSONPath expression. Something like `$[*].foo ? (@.id > 100)` or just `$[*].id` can't be translated to an "array path" to begin with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, that's what I meant by *"reasonably" possible*.